# How to search "\....\" using regexp in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

In my indexed data, I am having some documents which are having values like this -

"exclude y:\dkj....\sdfisd\sdfsdf\asdfai"

My requirement is to search all the documents having such entries based on "\....\". So for this I am using "regexp".
Currently I have used below regular expression for this, but it didn't worked out for me -

1. ".*\\(\.\.\.\.)\\.*"
2. ".*?[\.]{4}.*"
3. ".*\\[\.]{4}\\.*"

Below is the part of my query which I am firing to elasticsearch.

```
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ {
            "query_string" : {
              "query" : "\"DC2\"",
              "default_field" : "COLLECTOR_NAME"
            }
          }, {
            "regexp" : {
              "RAW_EVENT_DATA" : {
                "value" : ".*?[\\.]{4}.*", 
                "flags_value" : 0
              }
            }
          } ]
        }
```

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Which analyzer is used for the fields you are searching in. If it is some default, chances are there are no backslashes and dots indexed and you'll find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is related to analyzer
Let us create type with following mapping

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title_raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add new document

```
POST my_index/test/1
{
  "title":"exclude y:\\dkj....\\sdfisd\\sdfsdf\\asdfai",
  "title_raw":"exclude y:\\dkj....\\sdfisd\\sdfsdf\\asdfai"
}
```

Now search it

```
POST my_index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp" : {
              "title" : {
                "value" : ".*?[\\.]{4}.*", 
                "flags_value" : 0
              }
  }
}
```

returns empty result

But not analysed field works perfect with regexp

```
POST my_index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp" : {
              "title_raw" : {
                "value" : ".*?[\\.]{4}.*", 
                "flags_value" : 0
              }
  }
}
```

You can check [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html) to get an idea why it is happening. Because you are using standard analyzer part of information is lost on indexing stage and not available during search.